# Android Oval Gradient

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, gradient

I am developing a custom View in Android and I need to create shadows below a couple of components. I have tried the [Paint.setShadowLayer()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setShadowLayer(float,%20float,%20float,%20int)) method but the problem is that the view is redrawing itself very quickly, and it seems that the system has a little trouble generating the shadow so the overall fluidity of the widget is harmed.

What I've done then is creating basic shapes with an alpha gradient, this way I can emulate a shadow; and the result is great in terms of speed. The problem is that I have one component which is a rounded square and I need to create an oval gradient to cast an accurate shadow; but I can't see how can I create it with the classes in [android.graphics.Shader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.html) package.

So my question is simple, how can I create an oval gradient in the same way that [LinearGradient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html) or [RadialGradient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RadialGradient.html) exists?